# Video Sets Private(locked) YouTube Data API

Tags: youtube-api, google-api-client

I have google/apiclient library in Laravel and used YouTube data API for uploading videos in YouTube with the help of it video uploads are possible but visibility sets as private(locked) even after "privacyStatus" is public, "selfDeclaredMadeForKids" is false in API parameters, and the exact video I've uploaded via normal upload process in YouTube then it became public.
Can anyone help to resolve this issue.